# z-index does not apply on a custom nested tooltip

Tags: html, css, tooltip, z-index

Here is my tooltip:

```
  .tooltip-content{
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 180px;
    background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 120%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .tooltip-content::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9) transparent;
  }

  .btn-tag:hover .tooltip-content {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

And here is the parent block

```
.btn-tag {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0.7em 0.4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
  }
```

The problem is when I hover over a `Block A` the tooltip is being hidden under a `Block B` even though its z-index value is higher.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y6udf6f8/1/)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `z-index` declaration establishes a local stacking context. So by specifying `z-index: 1` on the `.btn-tag`, you're establishing a local context for each button for the descendant z-index (the tooltip has a higher z-index "inside" the context of the parent, the first btn-tag, but then the second btn-tag has another context with the same z-index value and since it's after on the DOM it appears on top).

If you were to remove the `z-index` rule on the `.btn-tag`class leaving it by default, then it will behave as you require it.

Please find the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y6udf6f8/

Comment: The solution is so simple that it's just brilliant. Thank you for your help.